# Inner join mysql ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am attempting an inner join with MySQL to select data from two different tables one named 'Bank' which has a 4 digit integer with a column 'no' and a 2 digit integer and one named 'Goodness' which has a VARCHAR with a column 'no' and I would like to print all three pieces of data and I cannot figure out why I am receiving this error, here is my code:

`SELECT MAX(Payroll), no 
FROM Bank
INNER JOIN Goodness
ON Bank.no=Goodness.name
WHERE client = 'Josh';`

The error I receive is: Error Code: 1052. Column 'no' in field list is ambiguous

I think it is because both columns are called no? Can someone help please, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: FYI - your next error is likely to be lack of a group by clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix `no` column in the `SELECT` clause using the table name:

```
SELECT MAX(Payroll), Bank.no 
FROM Bank
INNER JOIN Goodness ON Bank.no=Goodness.name
WHERE client = 'Josh';
```

Ambiguity arises due to the fact that both tables, `Bank` and `Goodness`, share a column named `no`.

**Edit:** Your query most probably misses a `GROUP BY Bank.no` clause too, since `SELECT` makes use of an aggregate function like `MAX`.

Comment: correct answer (upvoted), but you might want to add the group by the OP is also missing

Comment: @Christopherous5000 Yes this is correct, I've edited my answer. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: I have now fixed this thanks! I actually need a WHERE statement to search WHERE PAYROLL = MAX to find the maximum integer on the payroll, would anyone be able to help with that please?

Comment: @DavidThomlinson You can use the query of this answer as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tell which "no" you need.
Bank.no or Goodness.no

```
SELECT MAX(Payroll), Bank.no
```